# Turbo Prolog: 420 PROLOG.ERR missing

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

I'm quite new in Prolog. I'm trying to find the nth term and sum of a Fibonacci Series.

```
/* Fibonacci */

predicates
    fibonacci(integer, integer, integer)

clauses
fibonacci(1,1,1):-!.
fibonacci(2,1,2):-!.

fibonacci(N, Term, Sum):-
    N1 = N - 1,
    N2 = N - 2,
    fibonacci(N1, Term1, Sum1),
    fibonacci(N2, Term2, Sum2),
    Term = Term1 + Term2,
    Sum = Term + Sum.
```

However while compiling in Turbo Prolog I'm getting 420 PROLOG.ERR missing on

> fibonacci(N2, Term2, Sum2),

Why is this happening? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fibonacci(N2, Term2, Sum2)` looks like `Sum2` isn't used anywhere else. Is that intended? Although I don't know why that would be flagged as an error. It should be a warning. You should also rethink your implementation. Two recursive calls is very inefficient and unneeded. If you search for "fibonacci" in this section of Stackoverflow, you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: ok.. searching on SO for better solution. But just interested to know what is the error? :)

Comment: @lurker I guess you figured it out right! Since I'm not using that term TP is throwing this. I just used a dummy variable to store the value like `dummy = Sum2`. Now the error shifted to this line..

Comment: I **strongly** recommend you try out SWI-Prolog instead of Turbo Prolog. It's free, it's from this century, it's probably used 100x as much and it has great modern libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Is that really the entire error message? It does not say *what* is missing?

> EDIT: According to comments below, Turbo Prolog's `=` does indeed
>   correspond to `is/2`, so the remarks below, which are correct for
>   Prolog, don't apply. According to comments on the original question,
>   the terrible error message might be a singleton warning for `Sum2`.

In any case: Assuming that Turbo Prolog's `clauses` part corresponds to standard Prolog, none of `N1`, `N2`, `Term` and `Sum` will be integers in your program. `=` means unification, *not* arithmetic evaluation. If you call `fibonacci(3, Term, Sum)`, then inside the call `N1` will be bound to the uninterpreted term `3 - 1`, *not* to the integer 2. The same goes for your other uses of `=`.

For the arithmetic part, you will want to use `is/2`: `N1 is N - 1`, `N2 is N - 2` etc. This will evaluate the right-hand side as an arithmetic expression and actually bind these variables to integers.

Without thinking about it too hard, it's not clear to me if this will result in a useful computation for `Term`.

Comment: I think that the part you pointed out is incorrect. Refer to `lyra.ifas.ufl.edu/ABE6644/prologexamples.txt`. Turbo Prolog allows `=` as assignment. So, I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: @Isabelle, unfortunately, Turbo Prolog (or Visual Prolog, or PDC Prolog, mostly the same) isn't very standard. In TP, they use declared sections of code, like `clauses` and `predicates`. Also, in TP, `=` acts like ISO `is/2`

Comment: @Apy I do agree with Isabelle here that your quoted error message seems incomplete. "Missing" what?

Comment: @lurker I also don't know! It's just that `420 PROLOG.ERR missing` ! Can a screenshot help?

Answer (score 2):

i guessing turbo cant find some file with error descriptions. looks like tp incorrectly installed? correct this and you get more informative message.

look at
http://rosettacode.org/mw/index.php?title=Fibonacci_sequence&action=edit&section=399
and modify it for not only finding Nth but Sum also.

you get something like:
----

```
% fibsum(i, n, fib(i-2), fib(i-1), fib(i), sum(i-1), sum(i))
fibsum(N, N, Fi2, Fi1, F, Si1, S) :-
    F is Fi2 + Fi1,
    S is Si1 + F.
fibsum(I, N, Fi2, Fi1, F, Si1, S) :-
    In is I + 1,
    Fn is Fi2 + Fi1,
    Sn is Si1 + Fn, !,
    fibsum(In, N, Fi1, Fn, F, Sn, S).
```

% fibs(i, fib(i), sum(i))
fibs(1, 1, 1).
fibs(2, 1, 2).
fibs(C, N, S) :-
    C > 2,
    fibsum(3, C, 1, 1, N, 2, S). % Generate from 3rd on
---
(barely tested on http://swish.swi-prolog.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Turbo Prolog cannot find the error messages file PROLOG.ERR.  That is normally installed in Turbo Prolog installation directory.

If the file is there, chek that the application path is correctly set under Setup->Directories->Turbo Directory